# Guice injection for dynamically creating objects

Tags: java, guice

I have a "Handler" interface for a message queue, something that has methods:

```
boolean canHandle(message);
void handle(message);
```

I then have multiple implementations for this interface, each of them canHandle() certain types of messages

When a message arrive, I do something like:

```
for (Handler handler : handlers) {
    if handler.canHandle(message)
        handle(message)
```

So, I need to build a list of "enabled handlers" that must be specified in a config file.

I could either specify the enabled handlers by class name (FQCN) or annotating the class by some name and referencing this name on the config.

For instance:

```
enabledHandlers = ("com.domain.handlers.HandlerA", "com.domain.handlers.HandlerB", )
#or
enabledHandlers = ("HandlerAAnnotation", "HandlerBAnnotation", )
```

in any case, somehow I will need to build those handlers inside my service, and they require injected parameters.

I believe something injector.getInstance(clazz) would work to build those objects, but it doesn't make much sense to have the "injector" going around my service when I need to create those classes.
I could also create them by reflection "manually" by clazz.getConstructor(...).newInstance(...), but it seems pretty dirty.

Any other ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use any framework (like Spring) that provides a Dependency Injection mechanism for you?

Comment: I'm asking specifically how to do this using Guice framework

Comment: Try a google search for "guice dynamic injection"

Comment: hk2 is an IoC system designed to dynamically add and remove service (plugins) during the lifetime of the process